# Optimal Mass Distribution Minimizing Average 2-Wasserstein Distance to a Set of Mass Distributions

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, optimal-transport, wasserstein

Given a fixed set of  $n$ points in 2D (Earth Movers distance Prpblem), $P = \{p_1, p_2, ..., p_n\}$, I am trying to find the mass distribution $\bar{M}$ that minimizes the average 2-Wasserstein distance to a given set of mass distributions $\{M^1, M^2, ..., M^S\}$

My questions are:

1. Is the optimal mass distribution $\bar{M}$ simply the mean of the mass distributions $ M^1, M^2, ..., M^S$?
2. If not, how can we find $\bar{M}$?
3. Are there any known algorithms or methods tailored for this problem?

Thank you in advance for any insights or references.